# Sorcery squares!

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

The following 5-by-5 squares of digits are not magic squares, but nevertheless they each have a crucial property which enabled me to generate them. What is that property? How could you generate more such squares?

```
3  3  5  8  9               9  5  4  8  7
4  5  1  4  7               0  1  7  2  8
6  6  3  1  9               4  8  2  8  2
2  2  9  5  3               5  2  8  1  0
6  4  8  3  2               2  3  5  3  6
```

Comment: `Math.random()`? :p

Comment: @Novarg I don't write troll questions! :-p

Comment: AND every row is zero, AND every column is zero.

Comment: @Aravind what??

Comment: Write every number in binary. And AND. I realize that's not the intended solution, though.

Comment: At first glance I recognized that the diagonal from the top left to the bottom right of both the squares follow the same pattern. Maybe just a random similarity though...

Comment: @ProGlockner: The same pattern in that they both contain numbers?

Comment: @ProGlockner what??

Comment: Any tips on direction to look (horizontal, vertical, diagonal) ?

Comment: I've counted the totals of the numbers, left has 118 right 100, so the difference is 18. Left has no zero's, right has 2. , So if 0 counts as -9 it is some sort of pattern. left has 3 9's(27) right 1 9 (27-9 = 18 also the difference of 18) but that would be just ridicoulous.

Comment: @SvenB You're barking up the wrong tree there. The answer doesn't involve any complicated messing around with sums etc., and will be obvious when you see it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first one

> writes the first 25 digits of $\pi$ in a spiral, beginning with 3 in the middle and moving off upwards and clockwise.

The second does the same for

> $e$, beginning with 2 in the middle and moving off upwards and counter-clockwise.

The property is that they

> represent [irrational numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) in [Ulam-type spirals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral).

To generate more,

> pick other irrational numbers and do the same.

Here's one for

> [Feigenbaum's $\delta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants#The_first_constant) (4.669201609102990671853203...), starting off to the left:

```
3  0  2  3  5
9  0  6  1  8
1  6  4  0  1
0  6  9  2  7
2  9  9  0  6
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice. Good job!